# annotation text without it being hand written

Tags: modeling, annotation

Okay, I'm making a basic model for a guy in my town, and I've put in the dimensions and all using the Measureit tools add-on. but i need actual labels or text made with like the annotation tool, id prefer to not have to use the text mesh. and i cant make neat lettering trying to hand write it with the track pad. does anyone know if there is like an extra add-on for the annotation tool for this? or if there is anything else i can do?

[image]

Comment: may i ask why you don't want to use text objects? because they would be rendered?

Comment: because its not really meant for rendering, its just here to be a basic "blue print" for something that will be build in real life

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the annotation part of MeasureIt.
Then you can parent it to any object you like.

[image]

Comment: i cant believe i didn't even notice that button, thank you, i will take that into account.